# Getting the key inside a PHP foreach loop in simple associative array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

After years of confusion I am trying to get to grips with PHP arrays and especially in combination with `foreach` loops.

There are various similar questions but I am really trying to understand why this is NOT working rather than make it work per se (will be using lots of `foreach` loops and arrays in more complicated stuff shortly).

```
$age=array("Peter"=>"35","Ben"=>"37","Joe"=>"37");
```

Have a simple foreach loop:

```
foreach ($age as $ages )
{
    n();n();
    echo($ages);
    n();
    $v="volvo";
    $key = key($age);
    if ($age["Ben"]==$ages)
    {
        echo "<BR><BR>Result is  $key is $ages <BR>";
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
35
37
Result is Ben is 37 
37
Result is Ben is 37
```

All fine but I was expecting the last name to be Joe.

I thought that a `foreach` looped through each array value pair as a `KEY VALUE` pair. So why am I getting Ben twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `foreach` in the following way: `foreach ($age as $name=>$personAge )`

Comment: Thanks have seen that but trying to understand what was going on in the original. What was I accessing by my original ` $key = key($age)`. Why Ben as answer. It looped twice with value 37...On the third time the VALUE was 37 but it came from Joe... Yes I can make it work using a `var =>var` form but still confused. Thanks for the pointer.